# Cannot Read Property Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, foursquare, google-apps

Cannot grab the follower count from the following URL. Shows up as blank. Am I grabbing the right parameters?

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=pages/search%3Fname%3DNintendo

```
function foursquareFriends(url) {

  var responses = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = responses.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var likes = data.response.results.followers.count;
  return likes;

 }
```

Comment: Where does `UrlFetchApp` come from?

Comment: and the url is for.......(doesnt work , cant see reponse)

Comment: @RoyiNamir does this URL work? https://api.foursquare.com/v2/pages/search?name=NBCNews&oauth_token=EXS4O3MXU0GQ4RHOMBQBOVIULEQ2PMF0PUMQ4ZI0VHR0GY4A&v=20130617

Comment: No JSON response is returning from provided https://developer.foursquare.com/... URL, just login/signup info

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić what do you mean? I'm grabbing it from this URL - https://api.foursquare.com/v2/pages/search?name=NBCNews&oauth_token=EXS4O3MXU0GQ4RHOMBQBOVIULEQ2PMF0PUMQ4ZI0VHR0GY4A&v=20130617

Comment: `data.response.results[0].followers.count;`

Answer (score 4):

You should do this (using [this](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/))

`data.response.results[0].followers.count;`

[image]

(And of course if you have more than 1 value - you should iterate).